# Extraer valor en datalist

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Como puedo extraer el valor de la consulta en mi `DataList`, tengo el siguiente fragmento en mi pagina aspx

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="" class="col-md-2">País</label>
  <div class="col-md-4"><input class="form-control" list="lpais" name="paisc" id="paisc" placeholder="Seleccione pais" onBlur="return searchCountry();"><br></div>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Administration %>" 
     ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Administration.ProviderName %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT ltrim(rtrim([name])) as 'City' FROM [Country]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div><datalist id='lpais'> 
         <% for (int i = 0; i < DataList1.Items.Count;i++ )
         {
            var namecity = DataBinder.Eval(Container.Item); %>
            <option value='<%= namecity%>'>
         <% } %>
    </datalist></div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</div>
```

Quisiera obtener el valor que trae la consulta, aproximadamente trae 500 registros y asignarlos al `option value`

Comment: ¿Has considerado usar un  `asp:DropDownList` en vez de un ItemTemplate?

Comment: Lo que pasa que quiero que mi input funcione como buscador y lo que hago es que con las nuevo de HTML5 utilizo el datalist, este cuando se crea guarda los datos y ya me da la opcion de yo poderlos buscar funciona como una lista, pero con buscador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo único que necesitas es mostrar los valores en un **DropDown**, el control **DropDownList** es el indicado. Utilizar DataList se aplica mejor en un escenario donde vas a seleccionar, editar y eliminar valores.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Administration %>" 
     ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Administration.ProviderName %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT ltrim(rtrim([name])) as 'City' FROM [Country]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList id="CityDropdown" runat="Server" DataTextField="City" 
 DataValueField="City" DataSourceId="SqlDataSource2" />
```

Ahora bien, si además deseas seleccionar el elemento (DropDown) utilizando jQuery, esto te será de utilidad:

```
$("#<%= CityDropdown.ClientID %>")
```

Comment: Me arroja el siguiente error "Los métodos de enlace de datos como Eval(), XPath() y Bind() sólo se pueden utilizar en el contexto de un control de enlace de datos."

Comment: acabo de actualizar la respuesta :) Por cierto, en tu query deberías tener un ID que haga referencia a City, a menos que solamente guardes el nombre de City dejando de lado la PK de City :D

Comment: Excelente tu respuesta, con el DropDownList pude solucionar mi problema :)

Comment: de nada hermano, éxitos con el desarrollo, dale con todo el power 2.0!!! :D

Comment: Hermano, sabrás de casualidad como convertir ese DropDown, para utilizar un autocomplete?